# Server Manager 2012 - FileServer.events.xml cannot be enumerated

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows

I've got server manager running on my Windows 8 PC and it worked fine up till now. When trying to refresh a certain machine running server 2012 I'm getting the warning:

> Cannot get event data

In details:

> events from FileServer.events.xml cannot be enumerated

The same applies for the local server manager of that server.

Now this is only a warning so not a show stopper but it does introduce red entries on the dashboard. I did some research, the most relative information I found is [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13444.windows-server-2012-server-manager-troubleshooting-guide-part-ii-troubleshoot-manageability-status-errors-in-server-manager.aspx) technet article. I checked permissions of the file, that I can read it with the user that I'm monitoring the server with.

Spot checked the file against the same on a different server and also copied over the one from the other server.

I'm still getting the warning and looking for some advice, I could uninstall and reinstall the File Server role but as this machine is connected to a SAN I would be reluctant to do it unless there is no other option.

To finish off the only thing that changed on this server is me uninstalling the Dell Modular Disk Storage Hardware Provider service which we don't use or need as per [this](http://forums.veeam.com/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=18083) discussion. Most likely this somehow caused the issue but I fail to see how can this be related.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: I am having a very similar if not the same issue, did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to File Server Event Log entries which couldn't be read for any reason, maybe an underlying HW/SW problem.

First try checking the System Event log for disk or access related errors, after that backup and clear the event logs.